# UCD agent relay hierarchy

Tags: ucd, urbancode

Considering the following case: one server, one agent and two relays. I would like to know if is possible to create an agent relay hierarchy to connect to the UCD server? Something like: Agent connects to Relay1 connects to Relay2 connects to UCD Server.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really have a relay connect to another relay. What you can do is make sure the agent connects to different relays in case one is not reachable. This can be done by changing 3 properties in the agent's installed.properties file.

- Append your server and relays to the `locked/agent.brokerUrl=failover\:` property, don't forget to add `?randomize=false`
- Append the hostnames to the `agent.jms.remote.host` property
- Append the ports to the `agent.jms.remote.port` property

For more detail, see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4GSP_6.2.3/com.ibm.udeploy.install.doc/topics/configure_agent_failover.html?view=kc

Hope that helps.